# How to set PATH variable to latex, so that I can use latex layer?

Tags: latex, auctex, spacemacs, path

[image]

I installed the latest version of MacTex, and I am sure the latex is in the Libray/TeX/texbin/, I just don't know how to set the PATH variable, also I cannot install the AUCtex, I assume these two are the same PATH problem. I have no idea how to solve these.

[image]

Comment: Can you compile a LaTeX document from the command line? How did you install AUCTeX?

Comment: I could use LaTex and pdflatex to compile and get the output PDF file, even I got some warning like `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 12--22`. The problem is I could not directly use latex or pdflatex in the commend line to do it, I need give the full path (such as '/Library/TeX/texbin/latex blabla.tex`), I think the problem is I don't have PATH variable to locate the executable.

Comment: What does this question have to do with Emacs? Yes, AUCTex is in Emacs, but this is a question about your OS `PATH` value, no?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't seem to be about Emacs.

Comment: Ok, where should I change the PATH value, I am new with the shell and command line interface. I've looked up some similar problem, but I still don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Ok, I think I solve the problem by adding into `.zshrc` with `export PATH=/Library/TeX/texbin:$PATH`, then the latex can compile! thanks :)

Comment: @bagMan: it sounds, as if you are using MacOS.  In that case, the clean solution would be, to /etc/paths or /etc/paths.d/.  That should ensure, that applications, you start from your Desktop, Finder, ... should also have the correct path ...

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `(setenv "PATH" "/usr/local/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin/:$PATH" t)` to your .emacs :)

Comment: Welcome to Emacs.SE!  In general, please add a little bit more explanation to your answers.  This specific question is off-topic, though, so it's not necessarily worth it this time around.