# How to keep keyboard focus on terminal after compiling tex?

Tags: focus, tex

My operation system is `macOS Catalina`. I am using `iTerm2` in order to interact with `emacs` and my default pdf viewer is `PDF Pro Reader Light`. When a `pdf` file is updated, `PDF Pro Reader Light` automatically reloads the document.

---

I am using [following keybinding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38377679/2402577) to compile the latex files.

> `C-c C-a` (TeX-command-run-all) will do the job in AUCTeX 11.89.

After compilation is completed the keyboard focus is switch into the default pdf viewer and also the pdf view pops up in front of my terminal.

**[Q]** Is there any way to keep the focus on the terminal after compiling the `tex` and prevent pdf viewer to pop-up?

Comment: It may depend on the system; e.g., on an older version of OSX there are arguments to open external programs in the background when calling `open` ...; or, when using Skim's `displayline` program it has an optional argument of `-g` to open it in the background, whereas `-o` causes it to acquire focus and be brought to the foreground.

Comment: I forget to mention the system, I am using `macOS Catalina`. As terminal its `iTerm`

Comment: Disable the "auto redisplay" functionality of your PDF viewer, or use a different one. Why not use the macOS default `Preview`? This really isn't Emacs related.

Comment: Force Iterm2 to always be on top. https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/-/issues/9047

Comment: @nega Thats a smart solution but I have to switch in between iterm and safari so I can't keep iterm2 always on top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have add following to my `.emacs` file by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43453441/2402577) @lucky1928:

> 1. Change `(setq TeX-PDF-mode nil)` to `(setq TeX-PDF-mode t)` will get pdf output.
> 2. Add below configuration to remove the compile prompt:

> `(setq TeX-command-force "LaTeX") (setq TeX-clean-confirm t)`

When I do `C-c C-c` compiles the latex file and focus remains on the terminal.

1. Set the `PATH` variable in `.profile` as:

`export PATH=$PATH:/Library/TeX/texbin`

2. Afterwards, I added following to force latex to compiled.

```
(setq TeX-PDF-mode t)
(setq TeX-command-force "LaTeX") 
(setq TeX-clean-confirm t)
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I improved my questions and updated `PATH` part where I also get from (https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/40882/18414). I just wanted to compile the tex document and on my system, pdf viewer will already automatically detects the changes. I don't know why focus was changing when I do `C-c C-a`.

Comment: I removed my comment above because it contained a partial misstatement ... I was previously unaware `setenv` had an optional second argument for `SUBSTITUTE-ENV-VARS` ... so I just learned something new.  Thank you for adding details regarding which external program is being used to view the PDF.

Comment: `C-c C-c` seems like compiles only the related `.tex` file that is open in the `.emacs` and seems like references file (`.bib`) is not take place during compiling (which actually considred when I do `C-c C-a`). @lawlist