# Export to Latex error

Tags: org-export, latex, path

I’m working on a new computer (MacBook Pro) and I copied my old `.emacs` file to the new computer. It all looked fine, but export to Latex `C-c C-e lo` gives the error below: (it works fine on the old computer)

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "File \"/Users/a/nano/exported-org-files/2023-08-27....")
  signal(error ("File \"/Users/a/nano/exported-org-files/2023-08-27...."))
  error("File \"/Users/a/nano/exported-org-files/2023-08-27....")
  org-compile-file("exported-org-files/2023-08-27.tex" ("%L -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %..." "%L -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %..." "%L -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %...") "pdf" "See \"*Org PDF LaTeX Output*\" for details" #<buffer *Org PDF LaTeX Output*> ((66 . "bibtex") (76 . "pdflatex")))
  org-latex-compile("exported-org-files/2023-08-27.tex")
  #f(compiled-function (file) #<bytecode 0x521ad801>)("exported-org-files/2023-08-27.tex")
  org-export-to-file(latex "exported-org-files/2023-08-27.tex" nil nil nil nil nil #f(compiled-function (file) #<bytecode 0x521ad801>))
  org-latex-export-to-pdf(nil nil nil nil)
  (org-open-file (org-latex-export-to-pdf nil s v b))
  (if a (org-latex-export-to-pdf t s v b) (org-open-file (org-latex-export-to-pdf nil s v b)))
  (lambda (a s v b) (if a (org-latex-export-to-pdf t s v b) (org-open-file (org-latex-export-to-pdf nil s v b))))(nil nil nil nil)
  org-export-dispatch(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-export-dispatch nil)
  call-interactively(org-export-dispatch nil nil)
  command-execute(org-export-dispatch)
```

I thought the error was related [to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117083/problems-with-pdflatex-in-emacs-org-export-as-pdf),  but it didn’t help.

I see that these lines are included in my `.emacs` file.

```
(getenv "PATH")
 (setenv "PATH"
(concat
 "/Users/a/bin" ":"

(getenv "PATH")))
```

How can I fix this? I use publish and export a lot.

---

Now, I tried export to PDF and I got this error `zsh:1: command not found: pdflatex`

Comment: Forgive me if this is too obvious but are you sure that TeX is installed on this computer?

Comment: @FranBurstall Thanks. I totally forgot that I needed to install TeX. So, Installed MikTex. But it still didn't compile. I wasn't sure if it was a different error, so pasted the new error in the question.

Comment: What happens if you open a terminal window and type the command `pdflatex --help`? Also, isn't MikTeX for Windows? Is that what you need to run on a MacBook? Maybe `texlive` would work on MacOS? But maybe you should add to your question the OS/version you are running.

Comment: @NickD installed `texlive` and now I get the help text when I do `pdflatex --help`. (I didn't get it before.) But I could not uninstall MikTex. Export still does not work.

Comment: @NickD I started with `emacs -q` and export to latex worked fine! What does this mean?

Comment: That means there is a problem in your init file. Bisect it to find out what the problem is - see https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/how-do-i-troubleshoot-emacs-problems

Comment: @NickD Thanks. I commented out small parts of my `.emacs` file and it always worked on the "test emacs". Finally, this is what's happenning: If I start emacs from the terminal with `emacs` (without `-q`) export to Latex works fine. But if I start emacs from the Launchpad, export does not work and I get the error. Why is this happening?

Comment: @NickD Should I ask this as a new question? When I start emacs from the terminal export works fine. When I start it as an application from the launchpad, export does not work. How can I fix this?

Comment: I would guess this is an environment variable problem: when you start it from the terminal, the shell has been initialized with approprliate values for environment variables (like PATH) and the terminal emacs inherits them and can find `pdflatex`. When you start it from Launchpad, that mechanism does not apply and the  PATH variable does not have the right value to find `pdflatex`. I am sure this question has been asked before and there might be an answer already. Search a bit before asking a new question. I will search too but I cannot do it immediately.

Comment: @NickD I found this https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27826/how-to-set-path-variable-to-latex-so-that-i-can-use-latex-layer and I added `(setenv "PATH" "/Users/a/Library/TeXShop/bin:$PATH" t)` to my `.emacs` but this didn't help.